# Web Server Setup giving strange outputs

Tags: objective-c, web-services, http

Im trying to connect to a server from an apple app. The company I'm using for the server is awful and and promise they have set it up as required (but I'm not 100% convinced).

On the server i have a simple php file that returns a string. Simply does nothing else no reading of files or anything just

```
echo "This works!!!!"
```

From the objective-c app i am trying to make a simple http request.

The following works

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Address"]];
```

works and returns a message.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Address"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

works and returns a message.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Address"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

returns the following

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</title>
```

Any ideas what could cause this, could it be the server.

Comment: Although you're using PHP to echo a string, it's not really a PHP question so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after many nights of googling and an expensive call to Microsfot Support i found out that i was sending the POST to the incorrect address. Simple as that, i was sending it to www.mywebaddress.co.uk/File       instead of www.mywebaddress.co.uk/File/.php